# jQuery hasClass not behaving after appending elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

As you can see, I am looping through each 'li' to get various elements and bind events. The function refreshThis() is getting called after a successful callback from ajax to "reload" the dom and get each elements again to bind my click events.

If I run:

```
console.log($(this).hasClass('expanded'));
```

I get multiple "true" and "false. It appears the click event is bound more than once.

If I don't run refreshThis() in the callback, my click simply doesn't work. I have tried using .on such as this:

```
$('#nearestStaticDIV').on('click', $fetchComments, function() {
```

instead of

```
$fetchComments.click(function() {
```

which results in all clicks being triggered at once.

**How can I make hasClass behave correctly, even after refreshing DOM?**

Thank you! :)

**Heavily simplified piece of code:**

```
function refreshThis(){

$postlist.children('li').each(function() {

var list = $(this);
var $fetchComments = list.find('h1'); // click this to fetch replies

function fetchReplies() {
...
}

$fetchComments.click(function() { // fetch replies

    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) { 
        ...
    } else {
        fetchReplies();
    }

});

$commentPostBtn.click(function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data) {
                refreshThis();
        });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});

});
}

refreshThis();
```

Comment: Save yourself the hassle of adding the event all the time and use [jQuery's on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).  Then you won't have to rebind, and you won't need to worry about doing it wrong.

Comment: `$('#nearestStaticDIV').on('click', 'h1', function_name);`

Comment: @ElYobo I am thinking it's a better solution. However, how would I loop through each 'li' children in that case?

Comment: @Sven Tried it. It ends up running fetchReplies(); for each children.

Comment: the second paramter `h1` is the element inside the `#nearestStaticDiv` where the function is trigger on click. I only see the js and no html so I assumed it was the H1. But if you use multiple `h1`s inside the staticDiv, then you should give the refresh H1 an special class, or if it is the first H1 then you can use `h1:first`.